# JavaScript Mutliple Counters

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am following a tutorial on Udacity. My task is to create a webpage which displays cat images. When I click on the image of a cat an counter for this cat will increase. Everything works as planed, but the onclick event does not get binded properly to the image.

This is my JavaScript file (the html simply adds this script to the body. But I have copied it for reference to the end of this question.).

What is going wrong with my onclick function?

```js
// create images from list of objects.
const images = [
    new Image("Lorro", "http://placekitten.com/200/300"),
    new Image("Locho", "http://placekitten.com/300/300"),
];

function Image(name, src) {
    this.name = name;
    this.src = src;
    this.alt = `This is the image of ${this.name}`;
    this.clicks = 0;
    this.increment = function increment() {
        this.clicks++;
    };
}

function createElements() {
    document.body.innerHTML = 
        "<ul>" + 
            images.map((image) => {
                return `<li>
                            <h2>${image.name}</h2>
                            <img src="${image.src}" alt="${image.alt}" onclick="${image.increment()}">
                            <p>${image.name} was clicked ${image.clicks} times.</p>
                        </li>`}).join(" ") + 
        "</ul>";
}

createElements();
```

Comment: This does not do what you think it does: `onclick="${image.increment()}">`

Comment: Also, I really don't think it's a good idea to create HTML elements using interpolated strings and `innerHTML` - not least because because it's slow, but mainly because you open yourself up to XSS vulnerabilities - as well as subtle gotchas with how expressions in `onclick` (the ancient HTML attribute) vs. `addEventListener` (the modern and preferred JavaScript  API for events) work.

Comment: @Dai: I know it doesn't do what I want :D. That is why I am asking how I should change the code such that it does what I should do :).

Comment: You can't bind a local object through a string. You'll need to either create a single global function as the `onclick` handler - or get a reference to the `HTMLImageElement` after its created to use `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the way your code is setup it won't give you the desired results.

What I would suggest is create a general handler and inside that check which cat image was click (*I've given an `id` to each image to easily figure out which image was clicked*) and then call its increment method.

#### Explanation for the `handleClick` method.

- The `handleClick` method gets the `id` of the image clicked using the `event` object passed to the click handler.
- Using the `id` get the correct `Image` object from the `images` array and call its `increment` method.
- And finally update the `innerText` of the `p` tag associated with this image (which I've grabbed using `nextElementSibling`).

**NOTE:** You need to update the DOM to reflect the changes.

```js
const images = [
  new Image("Lorro", "https://via.placeholder.com/100?text=Lorro"),
  new Image("Locho", "https://via.placeholder.com/100?text=Locho"),
];

function Image(name, src) {
  this.name = name;
  this.src = src;
  this.alt = `This is the image of ${this.name}`;
  this.clicks = 0;
  this.increment = function increment() {
    console.clear();
    console.log(this.name);
    this.clicks++;
  };
}

function handleClick(e) {
  const {id} = e.target;
  images[id].increment();
  e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = `${images[id].name} was clicked ${images[id].clicks} times.`
}

function createElements() {
  document.body.innerHTML =
    "<ul>" +
    images.map((image, i) => {
      window.copyFunc = this.increment;
      return `
<li>
  <h2>${image.name}</h2>
  <img src="${image.src}" alt="${image.alt}" id="${i}" onclick="handleClick(event)">
  <p>${image.name} was clicked ${image.clicks} times.</p>
</li>`
    }).join(" ") +
    "</ul>";
}

createElements();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function name and then paranthesis after the name like `click()`.

To achieve this in your case use `onclick="(${image.increment})()"`

`${image.increment}` returns a function, and then make sure to wrap the function name inside parenthesis `'(${image.increment})'` and then call it like `'(${image.increment})()'`.

```js
// create images from list of objects.
const images = [
  new Image("Lorro", "http://placekitten.com/200/300"),
  new Image("Locho", "http://placekitten.com/300/300"),
];

function Image(name, src) {
  this.name = name;
  this.src = src;
  this.alt = `This is the image of ${this.name}`;
  this.clicks = 0;
  this.increment = function increment() {
    this.clicks++;
    alert(`Image Clicked`);
  };
}

function createElements() {
  document.body.innerHTML =
    "<ul>" +
    images
      .map((image) => {
        return `
<li>
  <h2>${image.name}</h2>
  <img src="${image.src}" alt="${image.alt}" onclick="(${image.increment})()">
  <p>${image.name} was clicked ${image.clicks} times.</p>
</li>`;
      })
      .join(" ") +
    "</ul>";
}

createElements();
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the immediately invoked function expression.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you `onclick` assignment. Inside your template literal you assign to the attribute what your `image.increment()` call is returning. Since that function doesn't return anything explicitly, the default return value for Javascript functions is returned, which is `undefined`, resulting in

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="This is the image of Lorro" onclick="undefined">
```

There is no easy fix to this using `onclick` attribute, so I've refactored your code slightly to using a `class Imag extends Image`. Please also note that your function name `Image` was conflicting with the built-in `window.Image`, which is why I renamed it to `Imag`.

```js
class Imag extends Image {
  constructor(name, src) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.src = src;
    this.alt = `This is the image of ${this.name}`;
    this.clicks = 0;
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.addEventListener('click', this.increment);
  }
  
  increment() {
    this.clicks++; 
    this.closest('li').querySelector('.clicks').textContent = this.clicks;
  }
}

// create images from list of objects.
const images = [
  new Imag("Lorro", "http://placekitten.com/200/300"),
  new Imag("Locho", "http://placekitten.com/300/300"),
];



function createElements() {
  document.body.innerHTML =
    "<ul>" +
    images.map((image) => {
      return `<li>
    <h2>${image.name}</h2>
    <span class="image-container"></span>
    <p>${image.name} was clicked <span class="clicks">${image.clicks}</span> times.</p>
</li>`
    }).join("\n") +
    "</ul>";
    document.querySelectorAll('.image-container').forEach((span, index) => {
      span.appendChild(images[index]);
    });
}

createElements();
```